# UK Climate and Ecology Bill 2020

Tags: united-kingdom, legislation, climate-change

What can the proposed UK CEE Bill do that cannot already be achieved by the Committee on Climate Change and the Joint Nature Conservation Committee?

Comment: Are you talking about "what bills can do that committees can't" or are you asking if this bill creates specific new powers or responsibilities on the government. If the latter, it seems that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_and_Ecological_Emergency_Bill would answer this question... does it?

Comment: Yes, more what a bill can achieve than a committee can't

Answer (score 2):

A bill can create new primary law. As it does so it becomes an "Act of Parliament"

A committee can only create secondary legislation to the limited extent that they are empowered by a previous act.

This bill would create new legal responsibilities on the the government. A committee can't create new legal responsibilities.

Comment: What possible reasons could there be for not enacting this bill?

Comment: The reason would be so as not to create new legal responsibilities on the government.  Do you think the government wants to have these new responsibilities?  If not the government will instruct its MPs to vote against the bill, and parliamentary discipline means that most (all?) will.  Most private members bills have no chance of becoming law unless they have at least tacit governmental support.

Comment: Agree 100%, though it's interesting how much public support it has gained, and also how many opposition MPs support it, suggesting it could get possibly get through if there was a change of government in the future?